# How do I display and store the contents of a HTTP stream using Mule

Tags: esb, mule

I'm using MuleStudio 1.30 and I have a server (actually, the mock server that comes with gnip4j) that just streams messages that have the following pattern

> message_id
>
> JSON message

and the message_id is on its own line and the JSON is on its own line.

Basically it's simulating a stream from Twitter.

I did the tutorials, but I can't find any documentation on how to just read from a HTTP stream.

I tried using HTTP and Echo but I figure that isn't working because the HTTP response doesn't actually finish since this is a stream.

What I'd like to be able to do is to echo the message to the console and to be able to store it to disk.

Comment: Is your client keeping the connection alive and sending these patterns in HTTP chunks?

Comment: The mock server I have isn't sending it in chunks, it's just a continuous stream.

Comment: I'm not sure if my mule app is able to connect to it either. If I wget from my server, I get a response though.

Comment: The problem will be for Mule to keep the stream open while cutting messages to route internally. Do you need to POST anything when contacting the server or is it just a GET? If not, you may try using a PollingHttpConnector with keep-alive set to true, hoping this will be compatible with the long polls you want.

Comment: It seems to connect to my server now. I'm using Mule Studio so what I did was take a Poll scope and put a HTTP endpoint in it. I then attached an Echo component to it. I get this stack trace (http://pastebin.com/r0WByKpC). I see you said I need to cut the messages? How would I do that?

Comment: If you're familiar with gnip4j, the server is actually the mock server that comes with gnip4j.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not going to work with Mule OOTB. You could package gnip4j as a Mule module with DevKit to generate messages in Mule.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the gnip4j custom components yet. I'm just running their mock server they have which streams messages. Would I still need to use the DevKit? From the viewpoint of Mule, this should just be reading from an arbitrary server's stream.

Comment: The problem is that it's not a typical request/response interaction, that's why I was suggesting to wrap a client known to work fine with such stream and make it available to Mule via DevKit. Let's see if you get better answers on the Mule forum...